# What causes an Altair Chart to be displayed when it is the last statement in a JupyterLab cell?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, altair

I have a class that I want to use in JupyterLab. When the last statement in a JupyterLab notebook evaluates to an instance of my class, I want to display an Altair `Chart` representing the object of my class. What is the recommended way to do this? In the example below, it appears that the `repr` function is called on my class in this situation, so this is a hook that I can use to control what happens when the last statement in a JupyterLab notebook evaluates to an instance of my class. However, I'm not sure what to do next. I can call `display` on the Altair `Chart` representing my object and then return an empty string. However, it seems a bit strange to be returning an empty string instead of something more meaningful. For example, if I want to use `repr` in some other context to show a representation of the object, then I won't be able to. When I call `repr` on an Altair `Chart`, I get a string like `alt.Chart(...)`, so it seems like there must be some other way to control what happens when the last statement in a JupyterLab cell is some object. Is there a better way to do this?

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class RandomWalk:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self._data = pd.DataFrame({
            'x': np.arange(n) + 1,
            'y': np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=n)),
        })
        self._chart = alt.Chart(self._data).mark_line().encode(x='x', y='y')
    
    def __repr__(self):
        # When I use the following line for the body of __repr__, then
        # JupyterLab prints the string 'alt.Chart(...)' and does not display
        # the chart.
        # return repr(self._chart)
        # The following line displays the chart as desired, but it feels odd to
        # then also return the empty string.
        self._chart.display()
        return ''

RandomWalk(100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altair charts display via Jupyter's `_repr_mimebundle_` method. You can see Altair's definition here: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/blob/v4.1.0/altair/vegalite/v4/api.py#L1644-L1654

You can read more about this in the IPython docs: [Integrating your objects with IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html?highlight=repr_mimebundle#integrating-your-objects-with-ipython).

The simplest way to create your `RandomWalk` class might look like this:

```
class RandomWalk:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self._data = pd.DataFrame({
            'x': np.arange(n) + 1,
            'y': np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=n)),
        })
        self._chart = alt.Chart(self._data).mark_line().encode(x='x', y='y')

    def _repr_mimebundle_(self, include=None, exclude=None):
        return self._chart._repr_mimebundle_(include, exclude)
```